# How can I manipulate Python Requests/UrlLib3 to mimic or use Chromes TLS 1.2 Fingerprint (JA3)

Tags: python, ssl, automation, bots

I'm having some issues where my web scraping tool isn't working due to a website taking fingerprint of requests (JA3) and not verifying me as a genuine human. After much research in wireshark I have learnt how to make the token/hash but not too sure how I am to implement it.

Has anyone had experience modifying Requests to mimic chrome to this level?

Comment: just `pip install curl_cffi`